# Comparing one table in 2 schemas to find missing columns

Tags: oracle

I made my researches; I didn’t find something similar to my question. If my question is duplicated please excuse me because I didn’t find in my researches.

I have 2 schemas, schema1 and schema2, and both of them have the same 6 tables.

But not every table have the same column in the schema.

Exp: tab1 has 40 column exists in schema1 but tab1 has 38 columns exists in schema 2. So there are 2 missing columns I want to add them. There are data I need to insert.

I can insert them manually but it will take me time, isn’t there a simple query?

In my researched I found tools that help for that. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make sure that schema2 has exactly the same structures and data as schema 1?

Comment: @DavidAldridge yes it is , i am sure about it.

Comment: Why not use export/import to duplicate schema1?

Comment: sorry, i am not expert in oracle i know how to do comapre user objecrs, but how do that for duplicate schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will show the columns in schema1 that don't exist in schema2.

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length
  FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE owner = 'schema1'
MINUS
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length
  FROM all_tab_columns
 WHERE owner = 'schema2'
```

I edited the above to include Alex's suggestions to include the data type and length in the output.

Comment: You probably want to run it both ways to catch dropped columns, and you could add the data and length columns too to spot alterations to columns that exist in both.

Comment: @moudiz I don't see why you couldn't do it between servers, but you'd have to setup an Oracle database link on one instance that points to the Oracle instance on the other server.  You'd then modify the FROM statement in the above query for the remote server to include the database link (i.e. **FROM all_tab_columns@db_link**)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see differences from on sides use `full outer join`

```
select      a.table_name , a.column_name , a.data_type , a.data_length , 
            b.table_name , b.column_name , b.data_type , b.data_length
from        all_tab_columns a full outer join all_tab_columns b 
on          (a.column_name = b.column_name)
where       a.owner = 'OWNER_A'
and         a.table_name = 'TABLE_A'
and         b.owner = 'OWNER_B'
and         b.table_name = 'TABLE_B'
```